# Disable submit button/loading on the card on submit in JavaScript adaptive cards

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

I have a form while submitting the card I want submit button to be disable or need a kind of loading for the adaptive card so that can avoid continues submission of form
Could any one please help me

Card:

```
{
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "version": "1.3",
      "body": [{
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Hello !!",
          "size": "Medium",
          "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
          "type": "Container",
          "style": "accent",
          "items": [{
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "What was the type?"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
              "id": "call_type",
              "style": "compact",
              "isRequired": true,
              "errorMessage": " required input",
              "placeholder": "Please choose",
              "choices": [{
                "$data": "${Survey.questions[0].items}",
                "title": "${choice}",
                "value": "${value}"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "actions": [{
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit"
      }]
    }
```

and the card rendering code

```
var jsonTemplate = "some data",
  var jsonDate = "some data"
var template = new ACData.Template(jsonTemplate);
var cardPayload = template.expand({
  $root: jsonData
});
var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function(action) {
  alert("Ow!");
}
adaptiveCard.parse(cardPayload);
let renderedCard = adaptiveCard.render();
document.body.appendChild(renderedCard);
```

[image]

Comment: Are using Angular?

Comment: I am using React, it is a web application in that i am using adaptive cards

Comment: Oh, you should add your code here for better understanding

Comment: I have edited and added the code

Answer (score 0):

Normally the flow is disable submit button(or add loading mask) when the button clicked, then send the submit request to backend.

enable submit button(or remove loading mask) when response comes or the request fails.

Comment: sorry i think I have not phrased my question properly, i am talking about the adaptive cards submit button